# Irssi certificate, OpenPGP and SSH keys in a new install

Tags: ssh, backup, keys, irssi

I'm intending to perform a full fresh install of Xenial 64 bits on my laptop currently running Trusty 32, bits since my CPU is 64 bits capable.

I want/need to keep my current Irssi certificate, OpenPGP and SSH keys in the new install so my question regards how should I go about keeping them. Is it enough to backup `/home/username/.bazaar/`, `/home/username/.irssi/` and `/home/username/.ssh/` folders and just past these in the new install home partition and everything will work?

Are there any other folders (regarding what I mention in my previous paragraph) I should backup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, yes.

You may need to re-register and/or re-import the private keys from these locations, but you can do that after installing the respective tools.

However, you should make sure that you actually backed up the private keys and that they're valid. `md5sum`ming is good enough for this.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer my query. What about `~/.pki/`, `/etc/ssh/` and `/etc/ssl/`. Are those necessary, also?

Comment: @KorriganNagirrok IIRC, `/etc/ssh` is not needed. However, it's better to be safe than sorry. Back up whatever you think is relevant, and trim it back after you know for a fact that it's not.